# Why did my comment get deleted?

Tags: discussion, moderation, comments

On this question

[What's the difference between "and" and "&"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/77942/whats-the-difference-between-and-and)

I made the following comment

> The title should have been 'What's the difference between “and” &
>   “&”?'

It got deleted. Perhaps the wordplay was considered off topic. As you can see though, the following comment did not get deleted

> Well, & always evaluates both operands as it is bitwise, but AND can
>   be short-circuited depending on.... wait, wrong stack.

As well as this reply to me that was also not deleted

> @Goose To be clear, it should be 'what's the difference between "and"
>   and and/or & "&"?'

Should I avoid making wordplay comments like this in the future? Did my comment break a rule or etiquette in a way those two comments did not? Not too terribly worried about my comment, just looking for clarification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comments are temporary.

There's no reason for you to expect your comments to be there from one day to the next. It's likely that someone flagged your comment as "no longer needed" and the moderator who handled it simply judged it on the merit of the comment alone without looking to see if any related comments also needed to be deleted.

I personally don't get the "wordplay" you're talking about. I don't see the benefit of your comment. The comment that did not get deleted could easily be deleted as well but it also has 50+ upvotes, so I can understand why a moderator would opt to leave it. The response to yours seems as unnecessary as yours, so I'm guessing that, after reading this, the moderators may also delete it.

But please, the first paragraph is the [ruler](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

> Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer. They can be up-voted (but not down-voted) and flagged, but do not generate reputation. There's no revision history, and when they are deleted they're gone for good.

Some sites are more strict about comments than others. We're pretty loose on them here but they do get deleted when they're determined to be "noise".

Comment: You didn't get the wordplay, even with the other comment that played on that wordplay?  I'd say that's your loss, not the commenter's. Also, you don't see the 'benefit' of the comment?  Half the comments on M&TV are comedic, and most such comedy increases the entertainment value of the site.  Are you saying you don't think entertainment is a benefit?

Answer (score 3):

IMHO all of those comments are overly chatty and don't belong on the question.  None of them aim to help clarify the question or add to it in any meaningful way and are just visual noise.  I've flagged all of them as too chatty.

This sort of stuff is really what chat is for.  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888/the-screening-room